# MySQL get same values from 3 selects to one

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 selects:

```
SELECT wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
        AND (0 = 1
             OR 0 = 1))
       OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
             AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var1%')
            OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var1%'))))
GROUP BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_date DESC
```

SECOND:

```
SELECT wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
        AND (0 = 1
             OR 0 = 1))
       OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
             AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var2%')
            OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var2%'))))
GROUP BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_date DESC
```

THIRD:

```
SELECT wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
  AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
        AND (0 = 1
             OR 0 = 1))
       OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
             AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var3%')
            OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var3%'))))
GROUP BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_date DESC
```

As You can see they're same, but I changed values. And now I need to filter only same values for all 3 queries.

So If 1st select give me ID's 1,2,3,4,5,6 secound will give me 2,3,6 and third - 2,6 I need to get only 2 and 6.

I Hope that You know what I try to say :(

I tried just show them all by using INTERSECT, INNER JOIN, UNION, I don't remember what else, but always there is and error like this:

[image]

Can someone help me, please?

Thank You for all comments :)

Comment: There is no "intersect" in mysql - note how it's underlined in red in your very own screencap.;

Comment: Since they're from the same tables you could just combine the WHERE conditions and make it into one query. No need to handle them separately and try to join the results. And do remove the pointless 0 = 1 etc from there first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see  aggregation function so you don't should use group by but distinct and order by  in subselect 
and you can use an inner join between the table

```
select * from ( 

    SELECT distinct wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
    FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
            AND (0 = 1
                 OR 0 = 1))
           OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
                 AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var1%')
                OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                    AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var1%'))))
 ) t1 
Inner join ( 
    SELECT distinct wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
    FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
            AND (0 = 1
                 OR 0 = 1))
           OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
                 AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var2%')
                OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                    AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var2%'))))
    )    t2 on t1.id = t2.id
Inner join (
    SELECT distinct wp_e398be30f4_posts.*
    FROM wp_e398be30f4_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_postmeta ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.post_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships ON (wp_e398be30f4_posts.ID = wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_type = 'offer'
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_posts.post_status = 'active'))
      AND ((wp_e398be30f4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (33)
            AND (0 = 1
                 OR 0 = 1))
           OR (((wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'title'
                 AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var3%')
                OR (wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_key = 'content'
                    AND CAST(wp_e398be30f4_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%var3%'))))
    ) t3 on t1.id = t3.id
    ORDER BY post_date
```

Comment: It give me some errors: "5 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 14)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 14)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 24)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 891)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 1779)" but I found answer after read Yours. I pasted it below

Answer (score 1):

We finaly get it by using this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (select1) as s 
    INNER JOIN (select2) as s2
        USING (ID)
    INNER JOIN (select3) as s3
        USING (ID)
WHERE
    1 = 1
```

Thanks @scaisEdge for suggestion :)